# If we create object with const constructor in dart the object is created at compile time?

Tags: dart, oop, methods, constructor, constants

I know the const behavior this is compile time constant if we make variable const but what will be if object is const?

Comment: If it's constant, it's created at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

`const` in Dart is very useful as it guarantees a few useful things:

- no extra memory allocation for *equal* instances, as the memory required to allocate the object is *interned*.
- the object is deeply immutable.

The first ensures that you can compare two consts very efficiently, as two equal instances will also be [identical](https://api.dart.dev/be/175003/dart-core/identical.html), and that you save some memory at runtime by avoiding allocating memory for several identical objects (hence why in Flutter, it's very common to use `const` for style data, for example).

The second ensures that even mutable data structures cannot be mutated. For example, this would throw an error at runtime:

```dart
const myLanguages = ['dart', 'js', 'java', 'rust', 'lisp', 'erlang'];

void main () {
    myLanguages.add('haskell'); // can't change at runtime!
}
```

Error:

```
Unsupported operation: addError: Unsupported operation: add
```

That means anything created with `const` behaves exactly as a primitive value. You can't change it and it doesn't require extra memory allocation.

`const` is transitive as well! So, you can always feel safe that if you declare something `const`, nothing can accidentally "break" it.

```dart
const myBelongings = <String, List<String>>{
  'fruit': ['apple', 'pineapple'],
  'shoes': ['nike', 'puma'],
  'houses': [],
};

void main () {
    myBelongings['houses']?.add('new house'); // can't change at runtime!
}
```

Error:

```
Unsupported operation: addError: Unsupported operation: add
```

The only problem is that there are a few limitations to what can be made `const` as a consequence of the need for the compiler to be able to verify these invariants, but in many cases, the limitations are not a blocker.

Example:

```dart
const otherConstant = 'world';

// OK
const myString = 'hello ' + otherConstant;

String getConst() => myString;

// NOT OK, Dart doesn't know when a function is "pure" or "const"
const notValid = getConst();
```

This won't compile:

```
Error: Method invocation is not a constant expression.
const notValid = getConst();
                 ^^^^^^^^
```

This example could be fixed with [const functions](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1048) which may become a Dart feature in the future!